# How to configure openjpa logging in wso2as

Tags: wso2, openjpa, wso2-as

I am trying to see the SQL generated by openjpa on WSO2AS 5.3.0. I tried:
- to update system.properties in /tomee
- add openjpa.Log to persistence.xml, using a resource_local transaction but also with jta, with a File attribute, or with log4j
- adding log4j.properties to /log4j.properties

No matter what I try, I see no output from openjpa!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in logging-bridge.properties, the logging levels use the commons/jdk logging levels: so ALL / FINEST / FINER / FINE / CONFIG / INFO.

When changing the level for openjpa.jdbc.SQL.level=ALL and org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.logging.handlers.LoggingConsoleHandler.level = ALL, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure openJPA logging through the logging-brdige.properties file in the WSO2AS_Home/repository/conf/etc folder

Default levels are as follows

```
OpenEJB.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.options.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.server.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.startup.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.startup.service.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.startup.config.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.hsql.level = INFO
OpenEJB.rs.level = INFO
OpenEJB.ws.level = INFO
OpenEJB.tomcat.level = INFO
CORBA-Adapter.level = WARNING
Transaction.level = WARNING
org.apache.activemq.level = SEVERE
org.apache.geronimo.level = SEVERE
openjpa.level = WARNING
OpenEJB.cdi.level = WARNING
org.apache.webbeans.level = WARNING
org.apache.openejb.level = WARNING
```

You can refer to doc for more information
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Configure+Logging+using+Config+Files

Comment: I tried this, but when I put openjpa.level to TRACE, I still get no messages below INFO level. I do see some openjpa initialization, so it looks like a step in the right direction. Since SQL logging is on TRACE level, I still do not see what I want to see.

Comment: You can refer to http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_logging.html#ref_guide_logging_channels
system.properties file is located at WSO2AS_Home/repository/conf/tomee folder

Comment: As stated above, WSO2 does not log any openjpa messages below INFO level, even with the level set to TRACE.